# Drupal 7 theme_hook_suggestions not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

How do I add 2  for one view display override?

This is the code I have that works:

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'qrule') {        
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__qrule';        
  }
}
```

HTML template page called: `html--qrule.tpl.php`

This works fine! (thanks @Ionut.A)

But I also want to override the `page.tpl.php` too with `page--qrule.tpl.php` but when I add this:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'qrule') {        
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__qrule'; 
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__qrule';    
  }
}
```

PAGE template page called: `page--qrule.tpl.php`

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /var/www/vhosts/xxx/public_html/sites/all/themes/themename/page--qrule.tpl.php on line 1
```

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adding a theme hook suggestion for the page.tpl.php file you'll need to to it in `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__qrule';
}
```